# почему не устанавливается домен в cookie? php

Tags: php

```
на локалке создал файл cook.php:
<?php

  setcookie ( "test" , "test2fewfwefe", "/", "test.com") ;
?>

запускается он так http://localhost/cook.php

сохранятся в браузер как localhost и уже в нем :
Имя
test
Контент
test2fewfwefe
Домен
localhost
Путь
/

как установить домен не тот с которого открывается а другой к примеру test.com ?
```

Comment: Может, потому что надо ещё раз посмотреть какие параметры принимает [setcookie()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php)?

Comment: <?php

  setcookie ( "fff" , "fsfsfsfs" , 1000, "/" , "tes.com" , 1 , 1 ) ;
?>
так вообще не работает
<?php

  setcookie ( "fff" , "fsfsfsfs" , 1000, "/" , "tes.com" , false , false ) ;
?>

Comment: `setcookie("test", "", time() + 3600, "/123/", "test.com");`?

Comment: у вас сохраняет? я так тоже пробовал вообще ничего не появляется ни в локалхосте ни test.com

Comment: тогда так `setcookie("test", "", time() + 3600, "/123/", ".test.com");`